# Unable to understand this example (how many ways to choose which days to work)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am unable to clearly understand the solution of an example. This is example 19 of chapter 3 of *"A walk through combinatorics"* by Miklos Bona. Please walk me through it.

I am producing the question below:

> A medical student has to work in a hospital for five days in January. However, he is not allowed to work two consecutive days in the hospital. In how many different ways he can choose the five days he will work in the hospital?

Please explain me the bijection set. The choice of 27 as the boundary is completely unclear to me.

For variety consider the same question with say each day is followed by 5 day assignment. Now the bijection would be?

Comment: Where does the number 27 come from - the solution from the book? Could you provide that text as well?

Comment: Yes it is in the solution from the book. Here is the solution :

Comment: It says: Let a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 be the dates of 5 days of January that the student will spend in the hospital, in increasing order. The requirement that there are 2 consecutive numbers among the a-sub-i and 1<a-sub-i <=31 for all i is equivalent to the requirement that 1<= a1 <a2-1<a3-2<a4-3<a5-4<=27, where a1 is a-subscript-1 or a-sub-1. Others in same way.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks for editing the question so properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you denote non-working days by n and working days by w, you can divide the month of January as $n1,w1,n2,w2,n3,w3,n4,w4,n5,w5,n6$ with the following constraints:

- $n1 >= 0$
- $n2 >= 1$
- $n3 >= 1$
- $n4 >= 1$
- $n5 >= 1$
- $n6 >= 0$
- $\Sigma n + \Sigma w = 31$

Perhaps there is a graphical way of finding integer values that will satisfy all the above equations.

Comment: Yes. It seems so. I got the idea behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 26 non work days. There are 27 "gaps" among them (25 in between and one before and one after). The work days must have come from these gaps. Thus the number of ways is $\binom{27}{5}$. More generally, the number of ways of choosing $k$ non adjacent objects from $n$ objects in a row is $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$.